# How a running Work Manager service cancel ,when button click?

Tags: android-workmanager

**I through 5 repeating alarm in doWork(). But when i switched off, alarm is ringing. But i want to stop workmanager service when switched off.**

```
swAll?.setOnCheckedChangeListener({ _ , isChecked ->
             if (isChecked) {
                "Switch1:ON"
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                //workmanager service
                 mWorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance()
                 request= OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(worker::class.java).addTag("cancle").build()
                 mWorkManager.enqueue(request)

            }
            else {
                "Switch1:OFF"
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                 mWorkManager.cancelAllWorkByTag("cancle")
                
            }

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

To Trigger actions that involve user interactions, like notifications at an exact time like:

- Alarm clock
- Medicine reminder
- Notification about a TV show that is about to start

It's better to use just the `AlarmManager`, [Google blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/modern-background-execution-in-android.html)